# Tortoise SVN repo browser not showing UI

Tags: tortoisesvn

After I click on Tortoise SVN repository browser, the UI does not show up, but in Task Manager the process was started.

Tried, uninstalling and installing. Removed all cache. But Still nothing works out.

Please help to solve this issue

Comment: If it's TSVN 1.12 - install previous vesion

Comment: @Madhu, Try enabling and check in Tortoise SVN logs. "Right click" any folder -> "TortoiseSVN -> Settings". On Settings UI, on left hand side, click "Saved Data". Look at "Action log" section.

Answer (score 9):

Leaving this here for future googlers like myself. I encountered this problem in
TortoiseSVN 1.14.5, Windows 11. The repo-browser would just show the window title bar at the top with no content.

I worked out that the problem was it would try to open the window in the last used position (which was maximised on my second (non-primary) monitor), but it would also try open/move it to my primary monitor, which just left a blank window.

**The solution** is to un-maximise the window (e.g. press <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd>) or move the window to another monitor (e.g. <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>).

Comment: You're the man, Conman_123